# How to send the IP Address of a visitor along in Auth0?

Tags: auth0

I'm using `auth0` in the back-end as part of a signup/login system, everything's working great so far.

But i have noticed that all the users' accounts are apparently based in Ireland ( which is where my server's located at ).

I have pinpointed this issue to be due to the fact that it's my server sending the requests and not the front-end.

As such i was wondering if there was a way to pass the `Remote IP` of my visitor along with the calls to Auth0?

Comment: based on documentation, the api does not seems to provide this feature.

Comment: That's what i guessed, i'm gonna try sending a request with an X-Forwarded-For header, maybe that'll work :]

Comment: For anyone looking for a follow-up, i've asked the question on the auth0 forum as well. https://auth0.com/forum/t/no-way-to-set-ip-address-to-real-ip/5206/3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the password grant, you can send the `auth0-forwarded-for` header (similar to `x-forwarded-for`) along with the request. This IP will be used for brute force detection, etc.

More info here: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/using-resource-owner-password-from-server-side#sending-the-end-user-ip-from-your-server

Answer (score 0):

As a example you can use something like below

```
var request = require("request");

app.post('/api/auth', function(req, res, next) {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/oauth/token',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'auth0-forwarded-for': req.ip // End user ip
    },
    body: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
      audience: 'API_IDENTIFIER',
      scope: 'SCOPE',
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' // Client is authenticated
    },
    json: true
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) return next(error);

    // ...
  });
});
```